# Copying data from one attribute field to another using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I am standardizing several shapefiles.

How do I go about copying data from one attribute field to a new attribute field i.e. would I use the calculate field tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the field calculate tool would be the easiest, but you would have to add the new field first. 
the strps would be

- Add new Field to the shapefile using [ArcCatalog](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/adding-fields.htm) or the add Field geoprocessing tool
- Right click on the new field in ArcMap and choose Field Calculator or run the field calculator geoprocessing tool
- Click on the name of the field you want to use as the source

[image]

If the attributes are in different shapefiles then you will have to do a join first.